# Limit definition of logarithm

Tags: calculus, limits, logarithms, exponential-function, limits-without-lhopital

In the book "e: The Story of a Number" (Appendix 4), the author try to show the inverse relation between $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b^h - 1}{h} = 1$ and $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1 + h\right)^{1/h} = b$ in order to give an idea of the natural logarithm.

Here is how he proceeds textbook copied from the book:

> Our goal is to determine the value of b for which $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b^h - 1}{h} = 1$. We start with the expression $\frac{b^h - 1}{h}$ for *finite* $h$ and set it equal to 1:
>
> $\frac{b^h - 1}{h} = 1$. (1)
>
> Certainly, if this expression is identically equal to 1, then also $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b^h - 1}{h} = 1$. We now solve equation (1) for $b$. We do this in two steps. In the first step we get
>
> $b^h = 1 + h$
>
> and in the second,
>
> $b = \sqrt[^h]{\left(1 + h\right)} = \left(1 + h\right)^{1/h}$ (2)
>
> where we replaced the radical sign with a fractional exponent. Now equation (1) expresses $b$ as an implicit function of $h$; since equations (1) and (2) are equivalent, letting $h \to 0$ will give us the equivalent expressions
>
> $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b^h - 1}{h} = 1$ and $b = \left(1 + h\right)^{1/h}$.
>
> The last limit is the number e. Thus, to make the expression $\lim_{h \to 0}\left(1 + h\right)^{1/h}$ equal to 1, $b$ must be chosen as $e = 2.71828...$

Are the steps mentioned in the book correct in regards to the laws of limits? Especially when he wrote $b^h = 1 + h \implies \left(1 + h\right)^{1/h}$ (notice how he **removed the limit prefix**) then he put back the limit prefix and wrote $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{b^h - 1}{h} = 1$.

Also, he said equation (1) is an **implicit** function of $h$. I am not sure of what he meant, in regards to the limit definition he mentioned earlier.

Comment: Well, seems like an heuristic method of getting a practical definition of the number e. Nobody has any thoughts on this?

Comment: Some expository books on mathematics leave rigor aside. See this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1380870/72031

Comment: The idea of logarithm is contained in the limit $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{b^h-1}{h}$ and this can be taken as a definition of $\log b$. There is no need to invert it. A simple flaw in his argument is that $b$ is a constant and not some function of $h$ as he wants to portray later.

Comment: I consider such authors of math texts who leave aside rigor as guilty of a common crime called *intellectual dishonesty*.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh in short, what he wrote is just *gibberish* from a mathematical POV?

Comment: @ParamanandSingh yes he said that this limit definition is an *implicit* function of h, not sure of what he meant since a function can take any possible value, and that the limit here (with b as a fixed value) is supposedly the natural logarithm of a given value, so a constant.

Comment: I would not say it is gibberish, but it's incorrect or imprecise and more importantly it conveys a wrong notion of limit.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thank you. When can we actually treat a limit as an equation? Is it *correct* to solve for a variable (for instance b in the example I have) when in the context of a limit? I talk about finite limits here, so real numbers. Because the author *assumed* the limit existed at 1, can he actually solve for b and then proceeds?

Comment: Well a limit is a real number. Thus $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) $ is a real number and you can't equate it to some other number in form of equation. However $\lim _{x\to a} f(x, y) $ is a function of $y$, say $g(y) $ and then you can equate it to some number and solve for $y$. But then this requires a deep study of the function $g$. The case here is $f(x, y) =(y^x-1)/x,y>0$ and the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x,y)$ can be shown to exist for all $y>0$ and hence defines a very nice function called logarithm. And then we can solve for $\log y=k$.

Comment: The thing to note is that the solution can't be done starting with $f(x, y) =k$ like the author here is trying to do.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh ok. So you can *only* equate a limit of a real number when it involves another variable (as a function, so one must treat the limit as a number and NOT a function itself that tends to a certain value). Am I correct? Also, the author assumes that $f(x,y)=k$ but as $x \to 0$ yet this limit is precisely the logarithm, so he should start with a study of the function $g(y)=1$ defined by this limit and solve for y? Is that note the same thing (in short)?

Comment: Yes! It appears that you have now understood clearly the meaning of my comments.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh your answers are rigorous and helpful. I think that solving like he did for a certain value $g(y)=k$ when in fact this solving require a deep study of the function defined by the limit is just not rigorous but it is still correct. But I think he just wanted to go straight to introducing the number e as a limit, and so he could avoid introducing the logarithm beforehand.

Comment: More formally you can ask a separate question: suppose that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x, y) =b$ and suppose $f(x, y) =b$ can be solved as $y=g(x, b) $. Under what conditions can one ensure that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x, y) =b\implies y=\lim_{x\to a} g(x, b) $

Comment: The fact is that you cannot really be rigorous in introducing the number e without the logarithm, which turn out to be the limit he is trying to rewrite. The rewriting happen to give a strange limit which is in fact the number e itself.

Comment: You can introduce the number $e$ directly as $e=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+(1/n))^n$ and then study the related limit $f(x) =\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+(x/n))^n$ and study its properties. There is no need of logarithm.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh sorry, I meant, he *deliberately* rewrite $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{y^h - 1}{h} = 1$ into $\lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^{1/h} = y$. If we assume y is some kind of fixed constant, we find the number e.

Comment: The motivation for above definition of $e$ comes from the notion of compound interest which is compounded continuously at every instant.

Comment: Writing $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{y^h - 1}{h} = 1$ into $\lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^{1/h} = y$ ask for under what conditions (as you said) $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{y^h - 1}{h} = 1 \implies \lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^{1/h} = y$. This require a deep analysis of the first limit.